# extended OAuth2RestTemplate can not be wired

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I need to extend the provided OAuth2RestTemplate implementation because of an additional required behavior, which is not part of the OAuth spec.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get my extended class wired to other spring provided classes.

I defined my own bean factory methods but there are other bean factories (e.g. OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration) wich use @Primary for such methods.

I also tried something like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
 exclude = {
 OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.class, ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class, ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class} )
```

But the application start always fails with errors like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [oauth2RestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateX, userInfoRestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateY]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4658) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5277) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [oauth2RestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateX, userInfoRestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateY]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [oauth2RestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateX, userInfoRestTemplate, customOAuth2RestTemplateY]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determinePrimaryCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:358) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.SsoSecurityConfigurer.oauth2SsoFilter(SsoSecurityConfigurer.java:80) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.SsoSecurityConfigurer.configure(SsoSecurityConfigurer.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration$SsoSecurityAdapter.invoke(OAuth2SsoCustomConfiguration.java:107) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

How can I get my extended class wired to other spring provided classes?
I need it here for example:
SsoSecurityConfigurer#oauth2SsoFilter

```
private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oauth2SsoFilter(
            OAuth2SsoProperties sso) {
        OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = this.beanFactory
                .getBean(OAuth2RestOperations.class);
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually fixed that in Spring Boot `1.4.0.M3`. We [no longer create that bean and you have to create it yourself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5202). It is currently hard-coded to `@Primary` in the auto-configuration which was a mistake on our end (and the reason why you can't override it).

I am afraid you'll have to upgrade to Spring Boot `1.4.0.M3`. You could make it work in 1.3 by copy/pasting the configuration that you want to use from `OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration` and exclude that auto-configuration.

Comment: I switched to version 1.4.0.M3 and faced another problem:
there are more places, where OAuth2RestTemplate instances are created directly without using a bean factory:
    
    UserInfoRestTemplateFactory#getTemplate

Comment: And I already tried to exclude OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration, but this did not work.

Comment: "This does not work" is not very helpful. You shouldn't bother about `UserInfoRestTemplateFactory` as it's used internally and you shouldn't override it. If you need to, just define your own `UserInfoRestTemplateFactory` bean and override the `getUserInfoRestTemplate` method.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I stated "This does not work", because I already described this try in my initial question.
I need to change the UserInfoRestTemplateFactory to use the extended OAuth2RestTemplate class. But UserInfoRestTemplateFactory holds this as private member and also creates this within the private method OAuth2RestTemplate getTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details). There are also other classes, which use UserInfoRestTemplateFactory directly, so I'm not sure, if extending this class will help in all cases.

Comment: As a worksaround for the time being with Spring boot 1.3 we use a BeanPostProcessor that configures the OAuth2RestTemplate bean that gets created in the OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.